# Android custom DialogFragment custom positive/negative button design

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a custom DialogFragment (support library). I set the layout as @color/GhostWhite, problem is, I can't find a way to set the positive/negative button in the same color.

This is how I set the buttons:

```
        builder.setView(view)
    // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton("Shout!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   //publishStory(/*shoutText.getText().toString()"woww");
                   mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(WagDialogFragment.this);
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               }
           });  

    return builder.create();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can call `getButton` with `DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE` and `DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE` parameters for changing color of both buttons as:

```
Button okButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
// set OK button color here
okButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.GhostWhite);

Button noButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
// set NO button color here
noButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.GhostWhite);
```

Answer (score 1):

After you call create, you can call getButton on the AlertDialog returned and set the color on that button.