# Android App: Replace default button background with custom background in a Dialog Fragment

Tags: android-button, android-dialogfragment

What I'm trying to do is change the default backgrounds of a custom DialogFragment that I have written.  Normally, I would do this by changing the XML layout file, however, for a DialogFragment these buttons don't exist in the layout file.

In essence, I'm trying to get access to the setPositiveButton, setNegativeButton and setNeutral buttons in order to modify them.  Alternatively, I would next try to do this by getting them by id, however, since they aren't defined in a layout file, I do not have a corresponding id for them.  I've found plenty examples of how to modify the rest of the layout, but I can't find anywhere that positive/neutral/negative buttons are modifiable.

Ideally, I could do this in the following block of code:

```
.setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       ...
                   }
               })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469096/android-custom-dialogfragment-custom-positive-negative-button-design

Comment: Where do I add this code?  

'    AlertDialog alertView = builder.create();
        Button positiveButton =     alertView.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);'

inside of 'onCreateDialog' is always returning a null.

Comment: check my answer.. Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code ... The button instance is valid only after the dialog created. Hope this helps you.

```
public static class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment
{

    public static CustomDialog newInstance()
    {
        return new CustomDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            }
        });

        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL",new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            }
        });


        return dialog;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        Button pButton =  ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        Button nButton =  ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

        pButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));
        nButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  Just what I wanted, except I had to use setBackground to use my custom button background xml.