# How to set drawables for buttons in an alert dialog? in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I want to set an Image and two buttons in an alert dialog ,i have tried the below code,i can set the image ,but i don't know how to set icon's for buttons.And i also want to align first button on the bottom of another button like this screen shot.

I have tried this code to add an image

```
 public void showAlert()
 {
AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        MainActivity.this);

LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.alertimage, null);
alertadd.setView(view);
alertadd.setNeutralButton("Here!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {

    }
});

alertadd.show();
}
```

Comment: try creating custom class for dialog fragment and set it over there

Comment: or you can create theme for dialog as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691192/replace-button-background-of-android-dialogfragment

Comment: to create custom dialog see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using a simple Popup window.It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the XML layout file:

```
<Button
...
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/source" />
```

Or, you could do programmatically as:

```
mButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.source, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: can you give an example please?

Comment: In your case do something like this after `alertAdd.show();`
`Button neutralButton= alertAdd.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL); neutralButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.source, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create the layout u want (R.layout.alertimage) with the image and the buttons already inside, than inflate it to the dialog(and dont use the alert dialogs buttons).
than u can use alertadd.findviewbyid(R.id.button).setonclicklistener(...)

Comment: You mean ,the popup window ?